Sitecore 10.3 and 10.4 Solr 9.x compatibility
With Sitecore 10.4 released, the Solr version installed with and officially compatible with both 10.3 and 10.4 is Solr 8.11.2.
Considering the security vulnerabilities with Solr 8.11.2  and the subsequent Solr releases 9.x latest being 9.6.0 in April 2024.
Any recommendation or experiences running Sitecore 10.x versions with Solr 9.x versions?

Sitecore officially supports only Solr 8.11.2 (for versions 10.3.x and 10.4).
For all the newer versions the official status is:

no compatibility information or does not work

So what does it mean to you? You can try to run any other Solr version with your Sitecore application, but then if you experience any issues, you're on your own.
Sitecore Support will tell you that they cannot help you because you run Sitecore using unsupported Solr version.
What you can (and maybe should do) is create a Sitecore Support ticket and file a request to support Solr versions which has no security vulnerabilities.
And another thing is to make sure that your Solr is well protected in a way that even with know security vulnerabilities no one can access it to exploit them.

thanks Marek, I will reach out to Support. any personal experiences running Sitecore with Solr 9.x versions?
